# how to make custom numbers for date/time/mins and keep counting

Tags: javascript

I have an questions for you, thanks in advance for looking this question.

I couldn't find the best solution to keep the values and keep counting. 
my goal is that trying to convert current timestamp into a value, from that value number, the numbers will be keep changing every second as clock. In my code, I increase 8 points in every secs. But the problems is whenever I refresh the page, the numbers starts from "27216009".
Whenever refresh the page or when someone visit the page, the numbers from pages have to be same.

Source code is -> http://jsfiddle.net/Q5CwM/

Please can you have a look of it. thanks

Comment: Your question is really unclear. Are you trying to save data across page refreshes? Should it show the same value to every user, or just to one user?

Comment: erm, what is this line supposed to do? `if (tc <= 8 || tc <= 18)`

Comment: Alright,  to be clear - lets say. our date/time is Oct 20, 5:12PM, i just want to turn that into a value (e.g: 27216000). Then every sec "8" numbers will be added to that value. After next sec, the value will be "27216008". The numbers will be keep counting as timestamp.

Comment: if (tc <= 8 || tc <= 18) is the just office hrs (8AM to 6PM).

Comment: @XML guy - right, but shouldn't it be `(tc >= 8 || tc <= 18)` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a timestamp which is related to a number. When the user visit the site, the counter changes according the current timestamp and then every second add 9.

**Update:** http://jsfiddle.net/Q5CwM/1/

Code added:

```
var defaultTimestamp = 1319146319 //a default timestamp of a specific time;
var currentTimestamp = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000); //current timestamp in seconds
var change = (currentTimestamp - defaultTimestamp) * 9 + 27216000; //adds the additional value to the default
```

Comment: can you give me example, my mind is almost burst out thinking that algorithm , thanks in advance.